# Does making binding for constants when they are DATEs is reasonable in pl/sql?

Tags: performance, plsql, oracle11g

As we know binding constants is not recommended at all but I have situation when constant is date.
I use it as below:

```
' and some_date != to_date('''|| MY_DATE_IN_VARCHAR || ''',''' ||MY_DATE_MASK||''') '
```

Is it really efficient to convert this date all the time instead of binding it like below?:

```
' and some_date != :my_date'
```

and binding

```
 execute immediate my_sql using MY_DATE_IN_DATE;
```

This instruction in my context could by sometimes run for 300k records.
I suppose that this conversion is more loading than binding.
I know I can test it but I can't predict loading in the production so test wouldn't be adequate.

Has anybody met with similar problem?

Comment: Since the date is a constant, I'd say you probably won't see much performance difference between the statements. The overhead of doing a TO_DATE will be negligible.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I see one more advantage of using binding in such case: clearer code. Anyway I stayed with version without binding.